# How to grant access to App permissions?

Tags: permissions, app-permissions, python

I am trying to access the SharePoint API with Python, a part of which involves bypassing Multi Factor Authentication using an app, following the instructions here: [Setting up an app-only principal with tenant permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs#setting-up-an-app-only-principal-with-tenant-permissions).

However when I try to set the App's permissions SharePoint says "Sorry, only tenant administrators can add or give access to this app", despite me having full SharePoint admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to register the tenant scoped changes in the tenant admin server?

You can get the above mentioned error, even if you have sufficient rights, if you don't do them in the tenant admin server.

So instead of `https://[mytenant].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx` use `https://[mytenant]-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SharePoint 2019 and got the same error.

With On-Premise SharePoint one can use the Central Administration URL with suffix `_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`, so in my case this syntax works `http://HOSTNAME:PORT/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`.

I don't have enough reputation that I could just write a comment to Sandro's answer.